# Difference between use and run in Rack

Tags: ruby, rack

What's the difference between the `use` and `run` methods in rackup files? It seems `run` is always at the end of `config.ru`, but it seems as if you should just be able to use `use`. Enlightening resources would also be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use` is for middlewares

```
class MyCustomMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if condition
     env['set-header'] = 'Middleware Can modify the response & pass it into next middleware'
    end
    @app.call(env)
end
```

`run` takes an argument that responds to call and returns a final Rack response with a HTTP Response code like 200.

```
class MyApp
  def self.call(env)
   [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, ["OK"]]
 end
end
```

To understand the difference between `use`   & `run`. lets see structure of typically rack app.

**Typical Rack App**
Rack app includes multiple middleware(s) which respond to `call` but do not return final rack response & an Object that responds to `call` which returns final rack response which includes HTTP response code(200,404, 500 etc). so typically there will be multiple objects which act as middlewares & then a object which returns final rack response with response code.

**Difference between `use` & `run`**

Now with this,
it seems can we can invoke `use` multiple times, once for each middleware & `run` only once in a single Rack App. so `use` will only invoke a middleware, while `run` will run the rack object which will return final rack response with HTTP status code.

example `config.ru`

```
use MyCustomMiddleware
use MyCustomMiddleware2
use MyCustomMiddleware3
run MyApp
```

In case if anything above is wrong, Let me know. So I can correct it.

Comment: Is it possible to stop somewhere down the pipeline of middleware due to, say, an authentication error?

Comment: ^^^Yes. infact, similar method of auth is used by warden - an rack based auth used by all popular gems like devise. you can see its [source of #call method](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/manager.rb#L30-L49). At its core, the #call method is simply checking for a conditional & doing something. Same as given in my example ABOVE.